# Returning queries from couchdb using nano

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchdb-nano

i've written a simple module to handle my couchdb CRUD operations using nano, however i'm having hardship returning from the results i query from the couch database. My Code is as follows.
**couchdb.js**

```
//Select from couch view
exports.couchSelect=function (_db, document,view) {
    return _db.view(document, view,function(err, body){

            if(!err){
                var rows = body.rows; //the rows returned
                console.log(rows);
                return rows;
            }else{
                console.log(err);
            }

        }
    );
}
```

**routes.js**

```
var couchdb = require('./couchdb');
app.get("/orders", function (req, res) {
    var db = couchdb.couchConnect('ezyextension_orders');
    var insert = couchdb.couchSelect(db, 'orders', 'orders');
    console.log(insert);
});
```

On executing the returned output is only get Node http request parameters without the returned rows, need help to return the actual JSON rows queried.Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using nano which use callback to make async calls. Returning _db.view only return a void function. I added comments to tell you what is happening :

```
exports.couchSelect = function(_db, document, view) {
    _db.view(document, view, function(err, body) {
        //This will be called after the couchSelect request.
        if (!err)
            console.log("Callback : " + body.rows);
    });
}


//When you use it

var couchdb = require('./couchdb');
app.get("/orders", function(req, res) {
    var db = couchdb.couchConnect('ezyextension_orders');
    var insert = couchdb.couchSelect(db, 'orders', 'orders');
    //This is synchronous. This will be called before the callback is called.
    console.log(insert);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the callback callback explanation, i decided to use blue-nano which instead return a promise instead of a callback since promises are much easier to use.

Comment: Promise are indeed way cleaner and easier to use !

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use blue-nano which uses promises instead of callbacks and the code is as below.
**couchdb.js**

```
var nano = require('nano-blue')('http://localhost:5984');
//Select from couch view
exports.couchSelect=function (_db, document,view) {

    return _db.view(document, view);

}
```

**routes.js**

```
    app.get("/orders", function (req, res) {
    var db = couchdb.couchConnect('ezyextension_orders');
    couchdb.couchSelect(db, 'orders', 'all').spread(function (body,header) {
        res.send(body.rows);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    });

});
```

This works perfectly